# How to shutdown with consolekit without sysvinit (but with systemd)

Tags: shutdown, systemd, sysvinit, consolekit

I have systemd (and no sysvinit) installed on a Arch Linux box. However, I cannot shutdown/reboot with consolekit (dbus interface). `# systemctl {shutdown,reboot}` work just fine, so I guess it's because consolekit doesn't know how to contact the `pid 1` process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After having a look at the source code, it seems that consolekit(ck) uses a short script to do shutdown and reboot. These two scripts are installed as

```
/usr/lib/ConsoleKit/scripts/ck-system-{stop,restart}
```

in Arch Linux and they simply find and exec `{,/usr}/sbin/shutdown` to do that.

Therefore, there seems no way to configure ck to do that now (by normal I just mean simply edit some file(s) in `/etc`), and the work around is straightforward.

1. simply edit those two scripts to exec `systemctl {shutdown,reboot}`. (But at least on Arch Linux, it will probably be overwrite after each upgrading.)
2. simply create a wrapper script at `/sbin/shutdown` that do the right thing. (This will cause conflict if you want to install sysvinit later, but hopefully not a problem.)

I will also look for (and create if there haven't been one) a bug report on the problem and I hope it can be done in a better way in the future (really don't like to do configuration outside `/etc`).

NOTE: Arch Linux now have the systemd-sysvcompat package which provide these (`init`/`halt`/`shutdown` etc.) as symlink to `systemctl`/`systemd`.